# Yii2 Kartik Tree manager JSON-export

Tags: php, json, yii2

Instead of using the tree-view from this yii plugin I want to get only the Nodes formatted into a json string.

Is there any performant way to create this JSON-tree out of all nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a simple solution: Inherit from `\kartik\tree\models\Tree` and use the following code to get a JSON array. To get the tree simply run another function over the `$nodes`.

```
class Industry extends \kartik\tree\models\Tree
{
    public static function getJSON() {
        /** @var TreeQuery $query */
        $query = self::find()
            ->addOrderBy('root, lft')
            ->select(['id', 'active', 'name', 'selected', 'root', 'lft', 'rgt', 'lvl']);


        /** @var array|ActiveRecord[] $nodes */
        $nodes = $query->all();

        return $nodes;
    }
}
```